# Getting the week of the year of particular days, considering Monday as the first day of the week in Excel Formula

Tags: excel, datetime, excel-formula, date-arithmetic

I'm trying to find the week of the year of particular dates using a formula in Excel. I found that Excel is considering the Sunday as the `1st` day of the week instead of Monday as the first day.

I used the formula `=WEEKNUM(A2)` (where `A2` is the date row) and got the result as below

```
--------------------------------
|  Date      |   Week of Year  |
--------------------------------
| 5/16/2015  |        20       |
| 5/17/2015  |        21       |
| 5/18/2015  |        21       |
| 5/19/2015  |        21       |
| 5/20/2015  |        21       |
| 5/21/2015  |        21       |
| 5/22/2015  |        21       |
| 5/23/2015  |        21       |
| 5/24/2015  |        22       |
| 5/25/2015  |        22       |
--------------------------------
```

But how do I get the result as below (Considering Monday as the first day of the week)

```
--------------------------------
|  Date      |   Week of Year  |
--------------------------------
| 5/16/2015  |        20       |
| 5/17/2015  |        20       |
| 5/18/2015  |        21       |
| 5/19/2015  |        21       |
| 5/20/2015  |        21       |
| 5/21/2015  |        21       |
| 5/22/2015  |        21       |
| 5/23/2015  |        21       |
| 5/24/2015  |        21       |
| 5/25/2015  |        22       |
--------------------------------
```

Comment: [`WEEKNUM`](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/weeknum-function-e5c43a03-b4ab-426c-b411-b18c13c75340) has a 2nd, optional parameter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pass a second argument to `WEEKNUM`: `2` stands for Monday.

```
=WEEKNUM(A2, 2)
```

Comment: I have a question that is not related to the above question. I'm trying to find the end day of the month of particular date using the Excel formula ```=EOMONTH(A2,0)``` for the date ```6/17/2015``` but instead of a date I'm getting a weird number ```42185```. What might be the cause for this?

Comment: @R0bert format the cell with the formula as a date.  That is how Excel stores the date in question.

Comment: @R0bert: `42185` is Excel's representation of date June 30, 2015. Just format the cell as a date, and it will display the value formatted as a date.